# How to use VBA-JSON in Visual Studio VBA application?

Tags: json, excel, vba, parsing

I am novice in VBA, but I never thought I will have a problem like that anyway. Well, the problem is next.
I need to parse json from api in my VBA app. I am trying to use VBA-JSON library (https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON), cause I failed to find somewhere any other suitable solution for this task. The reason I have to write here about this, is that there are billions of guides how to install this library if you use Visual Basic in Excel, but no information how to do it if you use Visual Studio.
When following instructions I am trying to import this "JsonConverter.bas" into my project, I can do this, but it is not recognized correctly, as I can see.
[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUInF.png)

There is written, that:
"Add Dictionary reference/class
For Windows-only, include a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime"", and I added it in references.
[Reference is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTqTG.png)

Of course I get build errors when I am trying to run application.

So, could somebody tell me please, where is my mistake, and how to install this library?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You cannot create VBA projects in visual studio, only in VBE (VBA Editor in office apps). Have a read about VB.NET/C# (visual studio) vs VBA (office vba editor).

Comment: Thank you.
I found another json parser for VB.NET, it is called Newtonsoft Json.
Just in case somebody could need it. 
(Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq)

Comment: Yeah, that's a well known library with millions of downloads.